# Remove Padding from column in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Icons with columns added]

[image: Icons when no columns added]

The first image is when I add css to the icons. It looks perfect but not responsive. I have not used any .col values for that. here is the css code

```
.fb {
background: none;
float: left;
height: 37px;
overflow:hidden;
    }
.fb img {
transition: 0.4s;
overflow: hidden;
}
.fb img:hover {
margin-top: -37px;
}
```

And here is the HTML Code

```
    <!--Social Icons UL Starts-->
    <ul>
        <li class="fb"><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb"><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb"><a href="#"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb"><a href="#"><img src="images/gplus.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--Social Icons Ul Ends-->

</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--Social Ends-->
```

Now I added some column codes and padding attribute is added and the result is as it looks in second image. here is what i wrote in HTML

```
    <!--Social Starts-->
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 social text-center">

    <!--Social Icons UL Starts-->
    <ul>
        <li class="fb col-sm-2 col-xs-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb col-sm-2 col-xs-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb col-sm-2 col-xs-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb col-sm-2 col-xs-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/gplus.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--Social Icons Ul Ends-->

</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--Social Ends-->
```

What should I do here. I am doing something wrong but I cant figure it out.

Comment: I added you code to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLr5husk/) It looks fine to me exceptI don't have the proper icons etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 ">

    <!--Social Icons UL Starts-->
    <ul>
        <li class="fb col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb col-sm-3"><a href="#"><img src="images/gplus.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--Social Icons Ul Ends-->

</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Try this, for me is working.

Comment: This works. Thank you. A little problem though. The margin between two icons are too much. should I add margin-left:-10 for .fb?

Comment: `<li class="fb col-sm-3 mr">` where css class `.mr {margin-right:-5px}` and mr class add to all list items.

Comment: This looks perfect in large screen sizes but its not mobile friendly. The icons get cut off when the screen size is Ipad.

Comment: I have one solution, it isnt too popular, and many people dont like this. I can write to you, and you see do you wanna to solve problem on this way. Using v2.3.2 Bootstrap you can solve it. On bottom of page http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html you can see classes like .visible-desktop and .hidden-desktop and their behavior on some resolutions. Use first class to and give to your <ul> tag. then minimize browser on ipad size, create new list where <ul> tag will have second class and add appropriate css for this list. First list you will see just on desktop and second list on other

Comment: i will try this but i'd rather not use v2 of bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out :-

```
    <!--Social Icons UL Starts-->
    <ul>
        <li class="fb col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li class="fb col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/gplus.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--Social Icons Ul Ends-->

</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--Social Ends-->
```

Edit : Replacing class `col-xs-offset-1 to` `col-sm-offset-1` in order to complete grid of 12.

Comment: I tried this, the padding in the left is gone but padding-top is added somehow.

Comment: @SuHan you can adjust the padding top by explicitly giving CSS padding to it.

Comment: Yes, I did it but it effects other screen sizes